# How to auto-vectorize strided writes with GCC?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, vectorization, c99

When compiled with GCC 5.2 using `-std=c99`, `-O3`, and `-mavx2`, the
following code sample auto-vectorizes ([assembly here](https://goo.gl/ddxwF9)):

```
#include <stdint.h>

void test(uint32_t *restrict a,
          uint32_t *restrict b) {
  uint32_t *a_aligned = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 32);
  uint32_t *b_aligned = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 32);

  for (int i = 0; i < (1L << 10); i += 2) {
    a_aligned[i] = 42 * b_aligned[i];
    a_aligned[i+1] = 3 * a_aligned[i+1];
  }
}
```

But the following code sample does not auto-vectorize ([assembly here](https://goo.gl/ggB9Lb)):

```
#include <stdint.h>

void test(uint32_t *restrict a,
          uint32_t *restrict b) {
  uint32_t *a_aligned = __builtin_assume_aligned(a, 32);
  uint32_t *b_aligned = __builtin_assume_aligned(b, 32);

  for (int i = 0; i < (1L << 10); i += 2) {
    a_aligned[i] = 42 * b_aligned[i];
    a_aligned[i+1] = a_aligned[i+1];
  }
}
```

The only difference between the samples is the scaling factor to `a_aligned[i+1]`.

This was also the case for GCC 4.8, 4.9, and 5.1. Adding `volatile` to `a_aligned`'s declaration inhibits auto-vectorization completely. The first sample consistently runs faster than the second for us, with a more pronounced speedup for smaller types (e.g. `uint8_t` instead of `uint32_t`).

Is there a way to make the second code sample auto-vectorize with GCC?

Comment: So the only difference is the scaling factor (3 vs nothing)? Try adding 1 as the scaling factor explicitly. If that solves it, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: Or try commenting out the statement `a_aligned[i+1] = a_aligned[i+1]`, or rewriting it as `a_aligned[i+1] *= 1`. The compiler may not know what to do with your no-op self assignment other than to do exactly what you said to do with it.

Comment: @Jeff Indeed, the only difference is the scaling factor. Adding an explicit 1 does not make the second code sample auto-vectorize ([assembly here](https://goo.gl/dnjSaQ)).

Comment: @DavidHammen Commenting the line out ([assembly here](https://goo.gl/Gpfikm)) and rewriting it as a compound assignment ([assembly here](https://goo.gl/YLUmfb)) also do not work.

Comment: You can just remove line 2 since it is equivalent to the identity.

Comment: @Jeff The idea is to somehow let the compiler know that it's allowed to write to `a_aligned[i]` for odd `i`. GCC won't write to a memory location unless it's explicitly touched in the source; otherwise, the compiler could introduce subtle race conditions (imagine if another thread were mutating `a_aligned[i]` for odd `i`).

Comment: It can't necessarily do those writes with SIMD instructions because the granularity exceeds one element.

Comment: You might look at masked AVX loads and stores via intrinsics. I'll see if Intel 16 can generate them.

Answer (score 1):

The following version vectorises, but that's ugly if you ask me...

```
#include <stdint.h>

void test(uint32_t *a, uint32_t *aa,
          uint32_t *restrict b) {
  #pragma omp simd aligned(a,aa,b:32)
  for (int i = 0; i < (1L << 10); i += 2) {
    a[i] = 2 * b[i];
    a[i+1] = aa[i+1];
  }
}
```

To compile with `-fopenmp` and to call with `test(a, a, b)`.

Comment: There are two caveats to this approach. The first is that you lose the `restrict` keyword on `a` and `aa`, which may cause you to read back `aa` more than you need to. It's fine for the sample code provided (in this case GCC branches to the non-vectorized code if `a` and `aa` alias in a troublesome way), but in general it could result in more reads than necessary. For instance, consider if `b` were replaced with `a`; in this case, there are many extra `vmovdq` instructions generated that aren't needed.

Comment: The second is that at `-O3`, GCC will auto-inline `test()`. Which means at places where `test()` inlines, it will recognize `a` is `aa` and fail to auto-vectorize. This can be fixed with GCC's `__attribute__ ((noinline))`, but this still unnecessarily incurs function call overhead.